# Showing an interstitial ad after a sound has finished

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to android development and learning as I go, please go easy on me...
I'm working on a soundboard where I want to wait until after a sound is finished playing before an interstitial ad is displayed, my current code below doesn't initialise the ad:

```
button1 = (findViewById(R.id.button));
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dontbeanidiot);
                clickCount = clickCount + 1;
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp.release();
                            if (clickCount == 10) {
                                mInterstitialAd.show();
                                clickCount = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the code that does show the interstitial but on button press rather than after. What am I doing wrong?

```
button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.wouldanidiot);
                clickCount=clickCount+1;
                if (clickCount==10) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        clickCount=0;
                    }

                }
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp.release();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Well, shouldn't `mp.isPlaying()` return `false` in a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` as the whole point of the listener is that the playback was completed at that point(?). You now have your `mInterstitialAd.show();` inside that condition. Debugging the code would show you how exactly it works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this and now it works as I wanted. Yes, I'm an idiot.

```
 button1 = (findViewById(R.id.button));
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dontbeanidiot);
                clickCount = clickCount + 1;
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp.release();

                        }
                        if (clickCount > 10) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                            clickCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```